# How do I change css from server asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I would like to change my css values through the server to depended on the servers response. I tried using inline expressions but it didn't work.

```
@keyframes loading-1 {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(<%=cpuRightDeg %>);
    transform: rotate(<%=cpuRightDeg %>);
}

100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(<%=cpuRightDeg %>);
    transform: rotate(<%=cpuRightDeg %>);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I just added a `runat="server"` to my style and added my css through

```
style.innerHtml = style.innerHtml + newCss;
```